# Opposite of &shy;

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to **not** break a word at a specific point?
Something like the opposite of `&shy`?

I've set my text to `hyphens: auto;` but at a specific point the word breaks which is incorrect. I already set `&shy` at multiple spots in the word, but it still breaks at the wrong point.

I want to insert something in the html (no css or anything because it has to work editorial) that tells the browser to never break at this point no matter what.

Comment: Can you show us that part of the code so we know what we're dealing with?

Comment: I can try, but it's pretty specific I guess.

Comment: No sorry, I can't. It's inside a big website with CMS and I can't replicate it to make it look exact the same. Too many nested elements with css all over the place. Can break it down to only that. Sorry. But the question is more of a general question and in my opinion needs no code.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a way to instruct the browser that it's OK to break words, but NOT at a particular char you've decided - all other chars are OK. Is that it?

Comment: @Bigood Yeah, thats pretty much it. Just don't let the browser break at MY SPECIFIC spot. Or lets say still follow the rules of `hypens: auto` but not at at my spot.

Comment: Does wrapping the word in a span with the style `hypens: none;` would be acceptable?

Comment: What element is this text in? Span, li, etc? Or, what element *can* it be in? e.g. any restrictions?

Comment: The text will be in a `<h2>` or `<h3>`

Comment: Thx for closing my question. Thats not the same! I'm talking about a single word not a full paragraph.

Comment: I have the same problem. A word breaks (syntacticly correct) at a place where I would like to avoid it for visual reasons. Imo that's not the same problem as in the "duplicate question"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no explicit HTML special char to do this.

One workaround might be to specify your whole content to be breakable anywhere, and wrap the unbreakable parts of your word in a `span` without word-break.

Then, you can decide in your editor where you'll want the word to stop:

```css
.breakable {
  word-break: break-all;
}
.unbreakable {
  word-break: normal;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="breakable">Browser can break anywhere here, but not where I decide: on this <span class="unbreakable">specificsuperlong</span>wordofmine, the red part is unbreakable. </div>
<div class="breakable">If I want to decide a special position it can only split on, I wrap my special <span class="unbreakable">unbrea</span>k<span class="unbreakable">able</span> in two spans.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but will this word really be "never breakable"? Because it's a pretty long one I indeed want to break it with `&shy;` but only where I set it. Will this work? I test your idea tomorrow and come back here.